# 'int' object is not subscriptable : HOG SVM object detection in Python

Tags: python, svm

I'm working on an object detection project, while using HOG skimage and SVM. I'm trying
to save all my positive windows in a list using my SVM model that I trained, but I'm facing an error :
'int' object is not subscriptable on this line : `detect = model_.predict([features_window[i]])`

```
def detection_image(image):
    coordonnees,HOG_features = fenetre_coulissante_HOG(image)
    features_window = []
    #We will now loop through all the features collected by the HOG on each of the sliding windows
    #We will predict from our model whether we consider the window as positive or negative: whether or not it contains our object
    
    for features_window in range(len(HOG_features)):
        #For all the windows considered positive of our model we will record their coordinates
        detect = model_.predict([features_window[i]])
        if detect[0] == 1:
            features_window.append((coordonnees[:i]))
    
    
    return features_window
```

Comment: `features_window` is an integer, not a list. By doing `features_window[i]`, you're trying to access the `i`-th element of `features_windows`, which doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies on that line:

```py
for features_window in range(len(HOG_features))
```

Inside the loop, it will turn the `features` variable into an integer, instead of the list it originally was. If you change it to `for i in ...` it will solve the problem, but will cause a problem with `features_window[i]`, because `features_window` is an empty collection; maybe you're intending to use `HOG_features[i]`, instead?

Comment: Yes I was intending to use `HOG_features[i]`, thanks I'll try to chane my `in range`loop!